# How to do BDD in a winforms app

Tags: c#, winforms, unit-testing, tdd, bdd

I have a scenerio where I have to get some data from the DB and display it in a Grid View in a Win forms app. I have written a unit test for Presenter mocking my repository and view. The test checks that the presenter calls the GetData() method of the repository and then calls the Bind(data) method of the view.

I have also another Integration test for the repository that verifies that if there is some data in the DB it is returned by the repository.

Now comes the part of testing my view. I can think of no way to test my form and check if it indeed binds data to the Grid view but that is a separate question.

My question is that if I wanted to test the above scenario in BDD style then in Win forms there is no way for me to test that when I call a method of the presenter is the Grid View filled with the correct data. Does that mean that I can not do BDD on Win forms as I cannot verify the complete behaviour without mocking the view. If we mock the view then the entire concept of BDD is lost because one key player that is involved in the completion of the scenario is mocked and not real.

It is really confusing for me and don't know if anyone else out there has had similar question in their mind ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to use BDD when creating a winform application.

TestStack have a framework called [White](https://github.com/TestStack/White). Quoting their website:

> White is a framework for automating rich client applications based on
>   Win32, WinForms, WPF, Silverlight and SWT (Java) platforms. It is .NET
>   based and does not require the use of any proprietary scripting
>   languages.

As you are using C# I also strongly recommend you use [SpecFlow](http://www.specflow.org/) for your behaviour-driven development; it allows you to define feature and scenarios for your application in a technology agnostic format and creates boilerplate code to aid you in your BDD process.

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130602212800/http://devblog.cloudreach.co.uk/2012/05/behaviour-driven-development-in-net.html?showComment=1340875666314) is a good article which works through an example using Specflow for BDD and White for winform automation.

Comment: Plus one for sharing the article, I normally use MSpec for my BDD which just seems more developer friendly to me with only to worry about code. Personal choice but your answer is excellent for anyone who wants to use BDD in winforms.

Comment: As you didn't mention a BBD framework in your question I thought I'd suggest SpecFlow. I'll take a look at MSpec.

Comment: @BenSmith "Here" link is dead now

Comment: @Ehouarn I've replaced the dead link with a link to the article in the wayback machine internet archive!